# how to place a global variable in another section

Tags: c, macros, compiler-construction, global-variables

I was wondering if there is a macros that I can use to place a global variable in another section.
i.e my_array would be stored in bss. since it's uninitialized but I want to place it in .data section instead.

```
uint8_t my_array[]; 

int main()
{
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: What compiler? .

Comment: Post compiler of interest, else question has not general answer.

Comment: A) Why? B) Why?

Comment: Since `array[]` only has a 'type' and no size, it is unlikely to be anywhere in the resulting executable.  Suggest giving that array a specific size, I.E. `uint8_t my_array[1024];` AND reference it somewhere in the body of the code.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to put a size yeah. I'm also using gcc. Looks like dbush got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using gcc, you can use the `__section__` attribute to set the section:

```
__attribute__((__section__(".data")))
uint8_t my_array[5];
```

Note that you'll also need to set a size for it, otherwise you only have a declaration instead of a definition.